# How to display a column from multiple queried tables that has same name as column in other table?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.column, b.column FROM a, b WHERE a.userid = b.id
```

Would like to be able to differentiate which column to display since the columns in both tables have the same name.

Clearly, if I use `$row['column']` it only returns one of the values. I have tried `$row['b.column']` to differentiate the table, but that did not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
SELECT a.column AS aColumn, b.column AS bColumn FROM a, b WHERE a.userid = b.id
```

Comment: seems like it should be pretty easy.

Comment: Put some debug into your code to see what is contained in $row. That may show you what is going wrong. As you say, it should be pretty easy and this is the standard way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the column as you want using alias "AS", e.g:

```
SELECT a.column AS other_name, b.column AS b_column FROM a, b WHERE a.userid = b.id
```

Then you can call `$row['other_name']` or `$row['b_column']`